# How to calculate the volume of a vtk file

Tags: python, 3d, vtk

I'm just new to python and I can't seem to find a solution to my problem, since it seems to be pretty simple. I have a geometry on paraview, I'm saving it as a vtk file and I'm trying to use python to calculate it's volume.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import vtk
reader = vtk.vtkPolyDataReader()
reader.SetFileName("C:\Users\Pauuu\Google Drive\2016-01\SURF\Sim Vascular\Modelos\apoE183 Day 14 3D\AAA.vtk")
reader.Update()
polydata = reader.GetOutput()

Mass = vtk.vtkMassProperties()
Mass.SetInputConnection(polydata.GetOutput())
Mass.Update() 

print "Volume = ", Mass.GetVolume() 
print "Surface = ", Mass.GetSurfaceArea()
```

I think there might be a problem with the way im loding the data, and i get the `AttributeError: GetOutput`.

Do you know what might be happening or what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: which version of `vtk` package do you have if you `print vtk.__version__` ?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of `vtk` package you may want to test the following syntax if your version <= `5`:

```
  Mass.SetInput(polydata.GetOutput());
```

Otherwise, the actual syntax is:

```
  Mass.SetInputData(polydata.GetOutputPort());
```

PS: you can check the python-wrapped `vtk` version by running:

```
import vtk
print vtk.vtkVersion.GetVTKSourceVersion()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned `reader.GetOutput()` in `polydata`. From `polydata`, I believe you need to do, `polydata.GetOutputPort()`

Comment: Hi tdka, Thank you for your answer. I tried that and the same error keeps coming up `AttributeError: GetOutputPort`

Comment: if you replace the line `Mass.SetInputConnection(polydata.GetOutput())` with `Mass.SetInput(polydata)` the program will run, but I am not sure if it will do what you want because `vtkMassProperties` only processes triangles

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have VTK 6 , you can provide as input to a filter either the output port of a filter or a vtkDataObject :

```
Mass.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
Mass.SetInputData(polydata) #that is Mass.SetInputData(reader.GetOutput())
```

For understanding why these method are not equivalent when updating a pipeline, and for comparison with the previous version, see http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Removal_of_GetProducerPort http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Replacement_of_SetInput